# How do I end a line half way along the X axis in Google Charts Line Graph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I have an embedded line graph from Google Charts that is actively updated and shows some areas where data hasn't currently been collected, at the moment these fields are set to 0 which causes the line to go down to the bottom of the Y axis half way along, attached is a picture of this.

Is there any way to get these lines to stop where there is no data available instead of going to zero? I have tried removing the data from these fields but this causes an error that results in the graph not been generated.

Google Charts Line Graph

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `null` instead of zero (`0`)